# Prisma cursor based pagination

Tags: graphql, prisma

Just finished the excellent tutorial on building Prisma based graphql backend. They explain how to implement first-offset pagination here https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/.

Now I am wondering, how to implement cursor-based pagination?

Here are my types (they are the same as in tutorial):

```
type User
    implements Node {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    links(...): [Link!]
    votes(...): [Vote!]
}

type Link
    implements Node {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: DateTime!
    description: String!
    url: String!
    postedBy(...): User
    votes(...): [Vote!]
}
```

In the playground I am trying to query user information along with the links, created by the user:

```
{
  user(where: {id:"cjimzqrshb3nf0c29z1p7km0j"}) {
    email
    links {
      id
      url
      description
    }
  }
}
```

It gives me back all the links, created by the user. How can I paginate them? Links object does not have paging information while linksConnection does not fit inside user object.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the linksConnection related to the user, and therefore access cursors :

```
{
  linksConnection(where:{user:{id:"cjimzqrshb3nf0c29z1p7km0j"}}){
     pageInfo{
       endCursor
       startCursor
     }
     edges{
       cursor
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to send two requests to backend? One for user information and the second for user links? I thought graphql helped to avoid this exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement cursor based pagination with Prisma like this:

```
{
  users{
    links(first: 10, after:"some-id") {
      description
    }
  }
}
```

This is possible because the id and the cursor is the same.

Alternatively you can use offset based pagination like this:

```
{
  users{
    links(first: 10, skip: 30) {
      description
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering, how to user connections with Prisma? Your sample would work, but it lacks information that connection types provide (pageInfo etc.)

Comment: use `usersConnection` instead of `users` which exposes the Relay-style connection.